# Maven Assembly Plugin: Unpacking overwrites different versions of dependencies

Tags: maven, jar, classpath, dependency-management

I am using Maven assembly plugin with which I generate single Jar file with all dependencies for my application (unpacked by definition in `jarlib.xml` given here: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/7cc0730ae0fb6947cbda). This `dependency.jar` can be then put on class path with my `application.jar` and run as `java -cp application.jar:dependencies.jar my.class.Runner`. The problem are however multiple versions of the same artifacts when unpacking jars.

For instance I am using `org.apache.xmlrpc:xmlrpc-server:jar:3.1.3` which depends on `javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3`. In my application I need to use different, newer version of the `javax.servlet`, but when unpacking, the new version is skipped and the old one is used instead.

1. Is there a way to ignore the dependency given by `xmlrpc-server`?
2. Is there a way to prioritize the newer version of `javax.servlet`?
3. Is there a way to create single jar without unpacking the dependencies and being able to use them with `-cp application.jar:dependencies.jar`? When I tried to build the jar without unpacking, none of the inner jar classes were found when running the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you really want is the shade plugin - the ability to create a single jar with all of these included.  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html

Comment: This looks promising, but I can't make it work properly - with this pom.xml (https://gist.github.com/knyttl/33e5f1bebeac1ffe6f7f) - I can see the plugin is running, but in the end I have impression it has no effect - how can I grab its output with the following plugins? The output is: https://gist.github.com/knyttl/f47ec07bb573e871b25e.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found is using `<exclusions>` directly in the `<dependency>` tag directly in the pom, without any plugins.